# Navigate between Screens

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my application,I have complex navigation.

I have Shopping Details .Which is View Controller of Tab bar controller.

When I select the any Store Name from **Shopping Details View Controller** .It will pop to a Shopping List **View Controller** which is embed in Navigation Controller.

When Select the Edit Button from **Shopping List** **View Controller** .It will pop to another View controller which ADD Screen. It is also embed in Navigation Controller

When I click save from Add Screen .It will go to the Shopping List **View Controller**

When I click **Done** button from the Shopping List **View Controller**  .I have to navigate to  Shopping Details View Controller of Tab bar controller.

**Please provide me input. How to traverse to Tab Bar Controller ?**

I have tried below Code. It is navigate to StoreDetails View Controller.Not displaying Tab Bar Items

```
let storeDetails = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoreDetailsController") as! StoreDetailsController
        storeDetails.managedContext = managedContext
        storeDetails.coreData = coreData
        storeDetails.back = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storeDetails, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is interconnected . pushToViewController or popTOViewController or dismiss is not worked. so I have used unwind.

StoreDetailsController:
I have below code in  StoreDetailsController

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        print("Test")
    }
```

In my ShoppingListViewController I have unwind Done bar button to exit.

```
 @IBAction func done(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToVC1", sender: self)
       }
```

you can follow the below link for unwind

https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f

Answer (score 0):

If you do `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)` you should be back at the viewController that's just before the first one embedded in the navigation controller, which I believe is `Shipping Details`(the one where you "select the any Store Name").

Comment: Yes, I have tried out.  Its not working because it is traversed from the Add Screen

Comment: Can we traverse to the tab bar specifically

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "traversed". Regardless, you should try to go back in the view hierarchy, rather than trying to load again the initial view. Try to 'dismiss' (go back) to the view controller you need, rather than `instantiateViewController` and `pushViewController`.

Comment: Thanks. dismiss its work only when the bar button item clicked twice. I have achieved using unwindSegue.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell you're trying to push the controller you originated from to the stack instead of poping back to it. It's a bit confusing to get the whole picture from your post, can you share that part of storyboard as a screenshot? Can you at least provide a diagram if you're not comfortable sharing the storyboard? Thanks.

EDIT:

For poping back to your controller you could use something like this:

```
for controller in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {

  if let vc = controller as? StoreDetailsController {

    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
}
```

But i really can't tell if you don't share at least the diagram on how your controllers are arranged and where are they embedded.

Comment: Thanks. I have found that I have segue directly to the View Controller.Instead of his Navigation Controller. Now, i am facing when I press two time the Done button.The screen present to root controller.               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: It sounds like you have connected the controllers in a circle with segue connections. As i said before, share a rough diagram of how your controllers are connected and we'll be able to help you better.